# Reading blocks/binary data from a raw socket

Tags: c++, r

When binary data is loaded into the BaseX XML-database, each \0x00 or \0xFF is first preceded by an extra \0xFF. After adding all the \0xFF, an extra \0x00 is added. As example, `[1] fc fd fe ff 00 ff ff ff fc fd fe ff ff 00 ff` is converted to `fc fd fe ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff fc fd fe ff ff ff ff ff 00 ff ff 00`.
The following R- code reads from a socket and returns the original data:

```
socket_bin_reader <- function(in_sock) {
  string_read <- raw(0)
  while((rd <- readBin(in_sock, what = "raw", n=1)) > 0) {
  if (rd == 0xff) rd <- readBin(in_sock, what = "raw", n =1)
    string_read <- c(string_read, rd)
  }
  return(string_read)
}
```

Reading and processing each byte separately takes a lot of time so I would like to first read larger blocks of data and then remove the extra \0xFF before returning string_read.
When I increase n to 16 bytes, as expected my function returns `fc fd fe ff ff ff`. The first \0x00 is considered as the terminating 0-byte.

My first question is how I can make a distinction between 0-bytes that belong to the data, or to the final 0 stop byte?

At the moment, I am converting my R-code to C++.
My second question is how I should handle in C++ 0-bytes that are embedded in the binary data?

Ben

Comment: Store length of data beside of the data instead of using `0x00` as terminate mark.

Comment: I am using an existent server protocol for BaseX (https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Server_Protocol) which can't be changed..